# Finding cycles and shortest path in Web crawler

Tags: python

I am trying to make a web crawler that scans through a website. Right now I want to search for the shortest path to find the page that displays `GOAL` and also find and direct cycles along the way. Currently, I THINK my code is able to find the number of nodes(web pages) there are. These web pages contain lines of expressions that can be computed to numbers. These numbers are `appended` to the end of a template url that lead to another web page. This continues until a page hits `DEADEND` or `GOAL`

How my `url_queue` works right now is that I know the initial link and I work from there. I open the URL and scan/evaluate the contents and add the new URLS to the url_list

```
ex:

url_a,url_b,url_c
```

My `url_queue` function will go to `url_a` and then process the new urls and `extend` them to the `url_list`

```
ex:

url_b,url_c,url_a1,url_a2,url_a3...
```

If the url has already been visited, it will not be added to the `url_list`

Currently the my function outputs the number of node(web pages) found and the order of which each url is processed and extend. I'm not sure how I can find the shortest path to the `GOAL` page and also how to count the number of direct cycles.

My code:

```
def convert_to_link(url):      
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    output_expressions = response.read().splitlines()   #return each expression in a list
    num_list = []
    url_list = []
    for expressions in output_expressions:
        if expressions == 'DEADEND':
            _,_,url_num = url.rpartition('/')
            #print 'DEADEND AT ' + str(url_num)
            continue
        elif expressions == 'GOAL':
            _,_,url_num = url.rpartition('/')
            #print 'GOAL AT ' + str(url_num)
            continue
        else:
            num_list.append(evaluate(parse(expressions)))   # parse and evaluate computes expression
    for number in num_list:
        url_list.append(newpage_gen(number))    # newpage_gen creates a new url that can be put into browser
    return url_list

def url_queue(url_list):
    count = 0
    visited_count = 0
    visited = []
    path_list = []
    for url in url_list:
        _,_,number = url.rpartition('/')
        if number in visited:
            visited_count += 1      # count number of revisited nodes
            print visited_count
            path_list.append(number + "PATH")   # which node is revisited
            continue
        else:
            visited.append(number)          # add which numbers have been visited to visited list
            path_list.append(number)        # path list?
            print visited
            new_urls = convert_to_link(url) # visit URL in the list 
            url_list.extend(new_urls)       # extend to the end of the url_list to visit later
            count += 1                      # +1 for non visited node
            print count
    return count, visited_count
```